# set div to specific height in xhtml under webkit

Tags: html, css, xhtml, css-tables

**Goal:** remove the white gap in between the two rows of images:

[image]

repro case: https://jsfiddle.net/kromato4/5cyLvnut/

The gap does not appear under html, but crops up when I switch to xhtml (and the epub that this is going into expects xhtml).

here is the html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>divs to the rescue?</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid">
    <div class="gridrow">
        <div ><img src="https://i.imgur.com/pvh1qBn.jpg"/></div>
        <div ><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Mmnz4YT.gif"/></div>
        <div ><img src="https://i.imgur.com/3nAJxUE.gif"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gridrow">
        <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/C8mn56T.gif" /></div>
        <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Tic5I5b.gif" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the minimal css:

```
.grid {
    display: table;
    width: 585px;
    height: 580px;
}
.gridrow {
    display: table;
}
.gridrow > div {
    display: table-cell;
```

I've mucked with setting heights on the divs to no avail. The top row images are all 255 pixels tall, but the divs holding the images appear to be an extra 4 pixels tall. Also tried using table with rows and columns, but showed the same issue.  Any help appreciated as this gap is super distracting when the images are all panels from the same comic.

Comment: Minor nitpick: this is not caused by a difference between HTML and XHTML, but by using Quirks mode in HTML. If you were to use Standard mode, HTML would have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Define display block on image tag, See attached code

```
.gridrow > div img { 
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO

Set image as display `table`

```
.gridrow img {
    display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add just one css only

```
.gridrow img {
    display: block;
}
```